# How to inject a view using datatemplate selector?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, datatemplate

To solve this, I can imagine I need to use PRISM or a datatemplate selector. I'm not really sure. Well, let me explain my situation. I've got this class called BinaryProblem and is the model.

```
public class BinaryProblem<T> {
    public T Number1 { get; set; }
    public T Number2 { get; set; }
}
```

BinaryProblem is a generic class, so T can be int, double, decimal, or inclussive another one, `Fraction`.

```
public class Fraction {
    public int Numerator {get;set;}
    public int Denominator {get;set;}
}
```

The point is  was thinking create a view for the primitive datatypes and another one for the fraction. This is the view:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <..Something.. Text="{Binding Number1}" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="+" />
    <..Something.. Text="{Binding Number2}"  Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

Where says `<..Something..>`, I do not know what to do. The idea is, if `T` is a primitive datatype should draw only a textblock; but if is a Fraction datatype should show the next template or something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Numerator}" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Black" Height="5" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Denominator}" />
</Grid>
```

I don't want to create two views, I guess is it possible to avoid create two views? I mean, to have only one view and detect if must show an fraction template or the textblock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: First create data templates for the supported types:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Fraction}" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Numerator}" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Black" Height="5" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Denominator}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
                  DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}" >
        <TextBlock Background="Green" Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then replace the 'Something' part with a ContentPresenter:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Number1}">
```

Comment: it looks great, just one doubt. In the seconda template, the data is not only for int, in fact can be anothers.. here is the reason to use data template selector, am I right?

Comment: @DarfZon Use a `ContentControl` instead of a `ContentPresenter`, and make the default `ContentTemplate` be your generic template. Then use a `DataTrigger` to determine if `{Binding Number1, Converter={StaticResource TypeOfObjectConverter}` is equal to `{x:Type local:Fraction}` and if so replace the `ContentTemplate` with your Fraction template

Comment: @DarfZon You do not necessarily need a template selector here. Just add more data templates for the known types (primitive types does not actually need any specific template if the default textblock is ok). Rachel's idea is yet another way to handle the template selection based on the datatype without using a TemplateSelector (althoug there is nothing wrong using one). But no matter which is the method to choose the data template, you need to create one to be selected.